# What is the right way to look after a concert flute after playing it?

Tags: maintenance, flute

Inspired by: [Will my wind instrument be damaged if I leave it assembled?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/406/will-my-wind-instrument-be-damaged-if-i-leave-it-assembled)

I have a pretty standard metal concert flute. What is the correct strep-by-step procedure for after I finish playing it? I am already drying it but want to make sure I haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Dry the inside and use a separate, soft cloth to wipe down the outside.  This removes oils and residue left by your fingers (and lips :-) ), thus helping maintain the instrument's finish.

I would recommend always disassembling for two reasons. First, it's much safer in its case rather than being left (assembled) somewhere else. Second, you will want to clean the joint surfaces now and then as well, to avoid the risk of binding.

Comment: With the standard kit I've got, I have to disassemble it to clean the inside!